# Flutter: Copy image file from url to firebase

Tags: image, firebase, dart, firebase-storage, flutter

I'm trying to copy a user profile picture from an external service onto my firebase server. So far I have:

```
final File file = await new File.fromUri(Uri.parse(auth.currentUser.photoUrl)).create();
final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("profile_image_${auth.currentUser.uid}.jpg");
final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.put(file);
final Uri downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;

// add user profile picture url to user object
final userReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .reference()
    .child('users/' + auth.currentUser.uid);
userReference.set({'photoUrl': downloadUrl});
```

The very top line gives me the error: `Unsupported operation: Cannot extract a file path from a https URI`

What is the correct way to do this? Should this even be done client-side? (Should I just be passing this url to firebase and use a function to download it server-side?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File` only supports files on a file system.
To load content using HTTP use the `http` package.
See also https://flutter.io/networking/

```
var httpClient = createHttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.get(url);
```

and then get the data from `response.body`,
or

```
var response = await httpClient.readBytes(url);
```

to get it as binary (`Uint8List`)

See also https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/http/0.11.3+14/http/Client-class.html